# Perl: IO::Zlib seek workarounds

Tags: perl, zlib

I have a gzip file of a binary. I have opened it with:

```
    $fh = new IO::Zlib;
    $fh->open($file_list[$i], "rb") or die "Open: $file_list[$i] failed\n";
```

Then if I do a ..

```
$bytes_read = read $fh, $data, $entry_size[$file_idx], $offset;
```

I get an error.

```
substr outside of string at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Zlib.pm line 463.
```

Seek does not work. I have been told that there are workarounds to it.

Please advice

Thanx!

-SS

Answer (score 1):

`$offset` refers to the position in the target string `$data` and not to some position in the input file as you might assume. Insofar this has nothing to do with **seek** (as in the title). It mainly says that the string `$data` you have given to `read` is not long enough to have the given `$offset` and thus it is impossible to write at the given `$offset` in `$data`.